Azure ServiceBus REST API - Receive Messages on a Topic/Subscription
Does anyone have any examples of using the Azure ESB REST API to receive messages from a topic/Sub.
I can hit the subscription and get the subscription summary details, but can't see how to get the messages either singly or batched.
I have looked in Azure REST API and there are examples for Queues and language examples with SDK for various languages.  I want to explore the REST Approach since another similar question was answered here and noted the SDKs are wrappers around the REST API.  So I 'd rather just hit the REST API directly.
Using Postman initially but with a view to call the API from an integration platform.
Thanks in advance.
Tried GET AND DELETE verbs on the sbus url and with the URL obtained from service bus explorer.
Was expecting a bundle of messages, but get the errors below on those verbs:
GET

400
The request is not supported for the supplied api-version ''. TrackingId:de9fa084-0f97-4098-8a46-9193bd1e0ccd_G40, SystemTracker:sbus-pep-dev-ukso-001:Topic:satesttopic, Timestamp:2024-08-02T15:47:47

DELETE

400
The specified HTTP verb (DELETE) is not valid. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. . TrackingId:913095cc-f0e6-4b88-af2c-1db1c537e1c3_G40, SystemTracker:sbus-pep-dev-ukso-001:Topic:satesttopic, Timestamp:2024-08-02T15:48:13

I'm using this as the URL:
sb://<my base url>/satesttopic/Subscriptions/SATessSub  

which gets me to the unauthorized to delete subscription error,  which seems perfectly reasonable.
and
sb://<my base url>/satesttopic/Subscriptions/SATessSub/messages

to attempt to get a message or batch of messages and that gets me the DELETE error.
I must confess I don't know where to obtain the API version.
Thanks for looking at this.

share the endpoints you are using and the api version.

URLs added to question.

To receive messages from an Azure Service Bus topic subscription using the REST API, you need to use the DELETE method with the appropriate request URL and headers. Based on your error messages, it seems you encountered issues with API versioning and HTTP verbs, and you are not using the correct REST API URL.
The REST API URL should be in the following format:
https://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{topicPath}/subscriptions/{subscriptionName}/messages/head
or
https://your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/your-topic/subscriptions/your-subscription/messages/head


I referred to this MSDOC to receive and delete messages from an Azure Service Bus topic. To receive messages, you need to use the DELETE HTTP method with the following URL pattern:

For a topic subscription:
DELETE https://your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/your-topic/subscriptions/your-subscription/messages/head?timeout=60 HTTP/1.1  
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=your-namespace&sig=Fg8yUyR4MOmXfHfj55f5hY4jGb8x2Yc%2b3%2fULKZYxKZk%3d&se=1404256819&skn=RootManageSharedAccessKey  
Host: your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net  
Content-Length: 0


To generate Shared Access Signatures for Azure Service Bus, I used this MSDOC:

    private const string ServiceBusNamespace = "your_service_bus_namespace";
    private const string SasKeyName = "your_sas_key_name";
    private const string SasKey = "your_sas_key";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sasToken = GenerateSasToken(ServiceBusNamespace, SasKeyName, SasKey);
        Console.WriteLine(sasToken);
    }

    private static string GenerateSasToken(string serviceBusNamespace, string sasKeyName, string sasKey)
    {
        string uri = $"https://{serviceBusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/";
        string encodedResourceUri = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(uri);
        string expiry = ((int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds + 3600).ToString();

        string stringToSign = $"{encodedResourceUri}\n{expiry}";
        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sasKey)))
        {
            string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
            return $"SharedAccessSignature sr={encodedResourceUri}&sig={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature)}&se={expiry}&skn={sasKeyName}";
        }
    }

Sas token Output:

Azure Service Bus  Subscription Message:

Using Postman for Rest Api:


Thank you for the very complete answer.  I had got this worked out shortly before you posted.  My issue in the end came down to authorization in Azure which was off  across the board for receiving data.  Once I got that sorted I am able to use the rest client for PEEK and destroctive type operations.

glad to hear you resolved the authorization issues and can now perform PEEK and destructive operations with the REST client.

Well I didn't follow the solution,  but it seems to be great information.
